# I'm having trouble identifying what's causing this Java runtime error,

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm trying to build an application featureing three radio buttons in a dialog box. I'm experiencing a head-scratcher of an error. Here are the consistencies between cases I've noted:

- All the files are in my `java/bin/*` directory
- All erroring files use swing components **AND** are extending JPanel **AND** are extending ActionListener
- I can extend JPanel OR extend ActionListener without error
- All erroring files compile without errors or warnings
- All erroring files error at runtime
- All erroroing messages include a line that the classname is wrong (or missing?) even though I can see it in Win Explorer

Frustrated, I turned to [Java's code sample library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) to grab some code to test. The launcable applet runs fine, inferring that I have the proper version of Java to run the program. I downloaded the `RadioButtonDemo.java` source code, as well as the full project to my `java/bin/*` directory. It's all unzipped to the right paths and, except for extracting from the zip files, untouched since it left Java's servers, I get the same error.

[image: screenshot]

A link to the code I downloaded itself is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java).

I'm importing

```
package components;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

and not being all that familiar with `package` yet, I'm wondering if I need to get rid of tha; this is the firt bit of code I'm creatingfor this project...so I don't have any other package elements for the class to find...dunno if I'm thinking about that  though.

I'm running:

- IE 8.0.7601.17514 using Java 1.6.0_21
- Win7 6.1.7601 command line Java is 1.7.0_02.

Anyone ever see this before and/or know what to do?

Comment: What is your IDE and is it showing some errors? How do you start the programm? CMD or from IDE?

Btw. the error means that the class RadioButtonDemo is not found on the classpath.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace ? NoClassDef can also mean there was an Exception in initing the class. The underlying reason can be found on the full trace.

Comment: *All the files are in my `java/bin/` directory* is going to be troublesome. The `.class` files must be in a package structure in the `java/bin` directory. `java/bin/components/RadioButtonDemo.class`. Or even `java/bin/classes/components/RadioButtonDemo.class` depending on your classpath.

Comment: @Adrian - No IDE, just TextPad text editor and running from the command line. See pic I just uploaded.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Move that `RadioButtonDemo.class` file into a folder called `components` and try again, it will work.

Comment: @maba - excellent hint. Just ran fine after I commented out `package components`. Like I said, I've not explored the `package` piece of Java extensively yet. Now at least I know how it's used and have something with which to experiment. Thanks!

Comment: @ maba ...and moving to `java/bin/components` worked excellently as well.

Comment: @dwwilson66 If you don't mind I will create an answer with that information that you can then accept, ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.class` files must be in a package structure in the `java/bin` directory.

```
java/bin/components/RadioButtonDemo.class.
```

Or even

```
java/bin/classes/components/RadioButtonDemo.class
```

depending on your classpath.

---

Simple test for your current build is to  move that `RadioButtonDemo.class` file into a folder called `components` and try again, it will work

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your Java versions (if not only for security reasons)
2. Make sure your directory structure matches the package declarations. It seems like RadioButtonDemo is not located in the correct directory.

Comment: #1; waiting for IT to roll that out. that's the nature of our environment...  :|

Comment: #2; I've looked at the `build-impl.xml` file that came with the zip, nothing jumps out at me, but then I really don't knwo what I'm looking for. :) There's no XML tag `<directory structure you need to use>` or similar...

Comment: In Java, all files must be placed in the directories matching their package declarations. That means RadioButtonDemo.class from package components must be places in bin/components (not just in bin). Same goes for the source fils: RadioButtonDemo.java must be located in src/components.